# Syntax Error DeploymentConfig Magento2.4.3

Tags: magento2

```
syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting ';'#0 /var/www/html/myproject/vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig\Reader->load()
```

I am getting the above error when i am running any command like cache,upgrade
my php version is 7.4 and megento2.4.3

Comment: can you share full error message.

Answer (score 3):

I got same error and checked config.php file which had error information when doing merging branches, modified that file and all fixed.

Comment: The exact line can be found through `php -l app/etc/config.php && php -l app/etc/env.php`

Answer (score 0):

You may have installed a module recently that has a config file not quite right. Also, you may have modified a config file in one of your modules and this modification is not quite right.

In both scenarios, you may either revert your change / disable the module.
You may disable your custom module one by one in the event that you do not know / can't work out the change

Just running the following `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` should tell you whether the error is still there.

Comment: its given same error on compilation command my php version is fine?its 7.4 and magento2.4.3

Answer (score 0):

in your file you forgot ; at the end of file. please add ; and try again.